# Delete method displays "forbidden" message

Tags: spring-boot, http, http-delete

I am testing a `Spring-boot` application that allow me to delete database contents. I gave temporarily access to all endpoints in my configurations:

```
 @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
      //Allow access to all endpoints
        http.cors().and().authorizeRequests().anyRequest().permitAll(); 
  }
```

And properties are :

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3307/cardb
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=******
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver

spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop

spring.jpa.show-sql=true

spring.data.rest.basePath=/api
```

Then I can get the content from the database by using the `GET` method in the app or from `Postman` But I do get:

> {
>      "timestamp": "2019-05-11T17:57:36.310+0000",
>      "status": 403,
>      "error": "Forbidden",
>      "message": "Forbidden",
>   }

when I try to delete with `DELETE` method.

Why do I have this error and how can I get the authorization to finally be able to delete objects from the database ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should disable the CSRF (Cross-Site Request Forgery) which is enabled by default for any method that modify state (PATCH, POST, PUT, and DELETE – not GET):

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
     //Allow access to all endpoints
     http.csrf().disable().cors().and().authorizeRequests().anyRequest().permitAll(); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it does work now. But from what it seems, disabling the CSRF will generate a security issue. Don't you think ?

Comment: Well, you said you are testing the application. So, it should be fine. Once you're done testing, you can remove `csrf().disable()` . CSRF protection is enabled by default in the Java configuration.